# Best practice in Gradle to configure Maven repositories globally

Tags: maven, gradle, repository

In Maven there is the `settings.xml` file in which I configure repositories (like Maven repository on a Sonatype Nexus server).

In my Gradle project the URL of the Maven repository is configured directly in my `build.gradle` file.

What is best practice in Gradle to configure repositories globally and outside the build file?

Answer (score 3):

I put the following in `%GRADLE_USER_HOME%/gradle.properties`

```
nexus.user=somecoolguy
nexus.password=guessme
```

Then I use this snippet

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        def repoUrls = [
            'https://mynexus:8081/nexus/content/groups/foo',
            'https://mynexus:8081/nexus/content/groups/bar',
            'https://mynexus:8081/nexus/content/groups/baz'
        }
        repoUrls.each { String repoUrl ->
            maven {
                url repoUrl
                credentials {
                    username project.properties['nexus.user']
                    password project.properties['nexus.password']
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could easliy turn the snippet into a [custom plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html) and perhaps improve it to

1. Use an encrypted password
2. Fail when `project.hasProperty('nexus.user')` returns false